# How can I broadcast and pick up a keypress event in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I already have this code:

```
<body ng-keydown="key($event);" ng-controller="appController">

function appController($scope) {

    $scope.key = function($event){
        console.log($event.keyCode);
        if ($event.keyCode == 38)
            alert("up arrow");
        else if ($event.keyCode == 39)
            alert("right arrow");
        else if ($event.keyCode == 40)
            alert("down arrow");
        else if ($event.keyCode == 37)
            alert("left arrow");
    }
}
```

But I have just one controller that when it is present inside of the body will need to call a function if the arrow keys are pressed.

How can I connect they events in the body from my appController down to the lower level controller which in this case is called questionController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are maintaining event on you main parent controller then $broadcast event to their children's inside `$scope`.

```
$scope.key = function($event) {
    $scope.$broadcast('key', $event)
}

$scope.$on = function(event, keyEvent) {
    console.log($event.keyCode);
    if (keyEvent.keyCode == 38)
        alert("up arrow");
    else if (keyEventt.keyCode == 39)
        alert("right arrow");
    else if (keyEvent.keyCode == 40)
        alert("down arrow");
    else if (keyEvent.keyCode == 37)
        alert("left arrow");
}
```

No need use `$broadcast` inside `$rootScope`, because all the child scope will listen the this event.

Answer (score 1):

In your parent scope use:-

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('key ', $event);
```

Capture this event in your child(more than one) capture it :-

```
$scope.$on('key', function (event, data) {
$event=data;
 console.log($event.keyCode);
        if ($event.keyCode == 38)
            alert("up arrow");
        else if ($event.keyCode == 39)
            alert("right arrow");
        else if ($event.keyCode == 40)
            alert("down arrow");
        else if ($event.keyCode == 37)
            alert("left arrow");

  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your scope in appController:

```
$scope.key = function($event){

    $scope.$broadcast('key', $event.keyCode)
}
```

Then the scope in questionController:

```
$scope.$on('key', function(e, key) {

    if (key == 38)
        alert("up arrow");
    else if (key == 39)
        alert("right arrow");
    else if (key == 40)
        alert("down arrow");
    else if (key == 37)
        alert("left arrow");
})
```